# Подскажите, что не так с кодом

Tags: javascript

Вот собственно код и вопрос к нему:

```js
let Arr=[];
let Arr9, Arr8, Arr7, Arr6, Arr5, Arr4, Arr3, Arr2, Arr1, Arr0=[];
Arr=window.prompt('Введите числа');
Arr=+Arr;
for(let i=0;i<Arr.length;i++){
 switch(Arr[i]){
   case 9:
        Arr9.unshift(Arr[i]);
  break;
   case 8:
        Arr8.unshift(Arr[i]);
  break;
   case 7:
        Arr7.unshift(Arr[i]);
  break;
   case 6:
        Arr6.unshift(Arr[i]);
     break;
   case 5:
        Arr5.unshift(Arr[i]);
  break;
   case 4:
        Arr4.unshift(Arr[i]);
     break;
   case 3:
        Arr3.unshift(Arr[i]);
     break;
   case 2:
        Arr2.unshift(Arr[i]);
     break;
   case 1:
        Arr1.unshift(Arr[i]);
     break;
   case 0:
        Arr0.unshift(Arr[i]);
     break;                  
   default:
     break;  
 }
}
document.write('Введено: '+Arr);
document.write('<br>'+'Получено: '+Arr9+Arr8+Arr7+Arr6+Arr5+Arr4+Arr3+Arr2+Arr1+Arr0); /*почему выводит undefined, а не переданные числа?*/
```

чтобы в результате при выводе на экран строки 'Получено: ' - выводились бы числа(целые, не отрицательные), которые ввёл пользователь, но в порядке убывания. Пример: пользователь ввёл 5654878. На экран строкой 'Получено: ' вывелось бы 8876554. Т.е. выводились бы числа, которые ввёл пользователь, но в порядке убывания

Comment: `let Arr=window.prompt('Введите числа');
console.log('Получено:', Arr.split('').sort().reverse().join(''));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Arr=+Arr;
console.log(Arr, typeof Arr, Arr.length); // add this line
for(let i=0;i<Arr.length;i++){
```

У числа нет свойства `length`, значит `i<Arr.length` будет `false` - выполнение не заходит в цикл.

Когда зайдет - будут ошибки, потому что ни одному `Arr...` не присвоено значение.

*Пардон, одному все-таки присвоено :).*